# Show that the CBC-MAC construction applied to a PRP is not collision resistant

Tags: hash, collision-resistance, pseudo-random-permutation, cbc-mac

[image]

I'm trying answer the following question. Yes, it is a homework question, so I'm not asking for the answer directly but would like to get some pointers on how to solve it.

So far I have spent several hours thinking about this to no avail. I know I'm missing something incredibly simple. I have tried various permutations of fixing messages m1 or m2 or m3 to be constant while others change and seeing how that affects the value of c3 when it is returned, as well as various permutations of fixing the messages to be 0^blen in order to try to find a collision. Hoping to get some pointers in the right direction.

Comment: Remember that you can _decrypt_ any block you want too, like the all-zero block.

Comment: Thank you @SqueamishOssifrage , when you say that I can decrypt any block I want to, you mean decryption using that fact that by definition a PRP has an inverse F^-1(k, F(k, x))? I'm sorry, new to crypto and really struggling with some of the core concepts.

Comment: Correct.  And it works for any block y, F^-1(k, y), whether or not you know the x such that y = F(k, x) in advance.  For example, can you use F^-1(k, 0)?

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage When you say use F^-1(k, 0), would that be a fact that I use literally as a decryption step in the algorithm I devise to find collisions, or used to show a relation between the ciphertexts in the given hash function? For example, is it true that c2 = F(k, F(k, m1)) = m1 when m2 is the all-zero block? Based on my understanding of PRPs it is guaranteed there is is **some** inverse function F^-1(k, y) = x. Is it true that for all PRPs F, F^1 = F(k, F(k, x))? I appreciate your help. I feel as though I'm circling around all the right concepts but need to put them together.

Comment: It is not true that F(k, F(k, x)) = F^-1(k, x) for a PRP—that would make an excellent PRP distinguisher!  (What is the probability that it holds for a uniform random permutation?)  The hint I'm giving is just to try to use the inverse direction of the permutation F in order to construct a collision.  Maybe try using the block x = F^-1(k, 0) whose encryption F(k, x) is 0.

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage Okay. I have been thinking about this more for a few minutes. I'm thinking there is a core axiom or principle I'm not understanding how to apply. My first attempt at using F^-1(k, 0) as stated was to try and pass that expression into the hash function as  either block m1 or m2 or m3 to see how that affected the final expression returned. I end up with something along the lines of F(k, m3 ⊕ F(k, F^-1(k, 0)) depending on which block I use as F^-1(k, 0). I have spent about 6 hours on this question, as a good gauge of how incompetent I appear to be in crypto.

Comment: Can you write F(k, m2 ⊕ F(k, F^-1(k, 0)) in another, simpler way?  Does the resulting expression appear anywhere else—perhaps with different numbering—in the definition of H?

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage  Thank you for bearing with me. I should probably get it by now. F(k, m2 ⊕ c1)  is the simpler way to write F(k, m2 ⊕ F^-1(k, 0)) but that is given in the problem so it seems circular to re-write it that way. Is there another way to write it? There is also F(k, m2 ⊕ F(k, (F(k, m1)))  but I wouldn't call that simpler. That expression is given for c3 with different numbering (m3, c2) later in the problem, but I don't see the connection. . In my collision-finding algorithm, will I ever have to use the result of a previous hash (c3) as an input block to make this work?

Comment: F(k, m2 ⊕ F(k, F^-1(k, 0)) is not F(k, m2 ⊕ F^-1(k, 0)).  Simplify it piece by piece: What's a simpler way to write F(k, F^-1(k, 0))?  Substitute that into F(k, m2 ⊕ F(k, F^-1(k, 0))); then simplify again, and so on. $$$$ Using the result of a previous hash lets you _forge_ messages, if you use CBC-MAC (verbatim) as a MAC where the attacker doesn't know the key, but that's different from finding a _collision_ under a known key.

Comment: Side note: If you've spent six hours on this problem, that's a sign not that you're incompetent but that it's a good time for a break—take a walk around a pond, do something with your hands instead of your head like cooking a meal or playing some music, and then come back to this after your mind has had some time to relax.

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage I think simplifying F(k, F^-1(k, 0)) is the missing piece. I don't know of any special facts about F(k, F^-1(k, 0)) that would be an equivalent expression, other than if we let m1 =  F^-1(k, 0), and so c1 = F(k, F^-1(k, 0)). If we take that, and substitute it into F(k, m2 ⊕ F(k, F^-1(k, 0))) => F(k, m2 ⊕ c1), then the final expression => F(k, m3 ⊕ F(k, m2 ⊕ c1)). If we do not let m1 = F^-1(k, 0), I don't know how to simplify the expression. Also, you're right! Taking a break now to play some basketball. Hopefully the blood flow helps. Thank you!

Comment: What is the defining characteristic of F^-1 in relation to F?  Might it help, perhaps, if you write it as $F_k(F_k^{-1}(x))$, or as the composition $(F_k \circ F_k^{-1})(x)$?

Comment: Actually, you don't need to compute $F^{-1}$; you can trivially find collisions even if $F$ is noninvertible.  Hint: suppose you have $m_1, m_2$ and $m'_1$ where $m_1 \ne m'_1$; how could you compute $m'_2$ such that $H(k, m_1 || m_2) = H(k, m'_1 || m'_2)$?

Comment: @poncho Thanks for your input. This is due tonight and still hoping to make a final push to be able to solve. Is m2' something that the collision-finding algorithm would compute with the results of the previous hash function? Or does it have to do with the malleability of the encryption? I think your comment is saying, "encrypt once with m1 || m2, change m1, and there is a predictable way you can change m2 in order to see (,1||2)=(,′1||′2)"...? Wonder is whether that predicability depends on prior input or if it is a trivial change on any m1 to form m1' and see m2 change

Comment: @poncho your hint is helping me down a good path I think. I'm thinking it's related to the insecurity of CBC-MAC for variable-length messages? Given x = (,1||2||m3), and y = (,1'||2'||m3'), we can generate a collision by XORING m1' with x and then computing  z = (,m1||m2||m3||(1' ⊕ x)||2'||m3')...We know that y == z?

Comment: That's a bit more complicated than what I was thinking (remember, unlike CBC-MAC, you know the 'key' $k$, and so can see the values of the internal variables $c_1, c_2$); however that is the right path.

Comment: Hint: Fix any distinct $m_1$ and $m'_1$, and any $m_2$. Since $k$ is known, you can compute $c_1$, $c'_1$, and $c_2$. Chose an $m'_2$ that will cause $c_2=c'_2$. Then build a collision from that. Extra hint: you do not even need to compute $c_2$, much less $c_3$.